# Етимологія слова "казнащо"

Tags: етимологія

Якщо для слів "хтозна", "бозна-який" зрозуміло, що вони походять від "хто" і "бог", то що може означати "ка" у "казнащо"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> <sup>[Етимологічний словник української мови Інституту мовознавства ім. О.О. Потебні НАН України](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0-)</sup>
>
> **Казна-** — початковий компонент неозначених займенників і прислівників *ка́зна-хто*, *ка́зна-що*, *ка́зна-який*, *ка́знаде*, *ка́зна-звідки*, *ка́зна-коли*, *ка́зна-куди*, *ка́зна-як* — результат скорочення і стягнення членів словосполучення *кат зна(є)*

Від себе можу порадити відейо по темі від Kozak Media: [Ремесло ката на українських землях у 17-18 століттях](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUKv1d904U8).